# Understanding error message "step halving factor reduced below minimum in NLS step"

Tags: r, error-handling, nlme

I am trying to run a `gnls` model (package `nlme`) in `R`, and am troubleshooting error messages. My model so far is:

```
Log13.5_Sum.T_gnls <- gnls(Weight ~ Asym/(1+exp((xmid-Age)*(v0 + v1*Sum.T))),
                           data = WTS_w13.5,
                           start = c(coef(Log13.5_gnls), v0= 0.16, v1= -0.0059),
                           na.action=na.omit,
                           control= gnlsControl(nlsTol=0.01))
```

which gave an error: `step halving factor reduced below minimum in NLS step`

I have tried increasing the value of `nlsTol` in order of magnitude increments up to 1000, but this produces the same problem.

I have previously solved a similar problem to this using `SSlogis` in `nls` to generate starting parameter values. These values informed the model `Log13.5_gnls` whose coefficients are the starting values here. The estimates for `v0` and `v1` come from a solution using a linear regression on a logged form of the problem, so I was expecting them to be reasonable.

Data.frame:

```
structure(list(Nest = structure(c(1L, 17L, 11L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 13L, 5L, 7L, 21L, 9L, 15L, 17L, 4L, 10L, 16L, 20L, 7L, 8L, 18L, 19L, 13L, 14L, 11L, 21L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 17L, 7L, 13L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 19L, 22L, 17L, 4L, 21L), .Label = c("WTSN00", "WTSN01", "WTSN02", "WTSN04", "WTSN05", "WTSN06", "WTSN07", "WTSN08", "WTSN09", "WTSN10", "WTSN12", "WTSN13", "WTSN14", "WTSN16", "WTSN18", "WTSN20", "WTSN21", "WTSN23", "WTSN24", "WTSN25", "WTSN26", "WTSN28", "WTSN29"), class = "factor"),
Hatch = structure(c(10957, 16177, 16181, 16165, 16185, 16188, 16181, 16165, 16189, 16189, 16193, 16195, 16177, 16177, 16181, 16200, 16173, 16189, 16188, 16182, 16176, 16181, 16180, 16181, 16189, 16185, 16193, 16177, 16177, 16189, 16181, 16177, 16177, 16165, 16189, 16181, 16176, 16181, 16177, 16177, 16189), class = "Date"),
Age = c(0, 6, 7.5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 9, 9, 9, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 9.5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10.5, 10.5, 11, 11, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 12, 12, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 13.5),
Weight = c(1.022, 8.1, 8.5, 8.8, 8.8, 9.6, 8.6, 9.7, 11, 9.9, 11.1, 9.9, 12, 10.5, 10.5, 7, 11.2, 11.9, 11.4, 11, 11.9, 11.2, 11.7, 9.1, 12.3, 12.3, 13, 11.6, 13.4, 12.2, 11.1, 12.7, 11.3, 12.2, 12.4, 11.8, 12.9, 11.2, 13.2, 11, 14.1),
Sum.T = c(NA, 313.851904139019, 375.724003527149, NA, 406.89428107332, 463.691957819221, 445.28632226469, NA, 415.486307859544, 429.22166483835, 448.628929837252, 436.477157418387, 480.998397305757, 505.76849873214, 465.046041424436, 529.914690217322, NA, 488.827490583208, 582.676479904347, 570.255184933855, NA, 594.21509635292, 703.48545276177,  559.086005290723, 569.478435100335, 593.644945574203, 581.137438612915, 572.523390933983, 630.703808278039, 584.949067548094, 692.972360805858, 690.676762264357, 698.225577774177, NA, 608.229461789316, 637.728055232582, NA, NA, 722.027054861407, 759.276720390869, 701.235205362319)),
.Names = c("Nest", "Hatch", "Age", "Weight", "Sum.T"),
row.names = c(NA, 41L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: The problem is not that the second option was too low. As the error says, there is no such element as `params[[i]][[2]]`. My guess is that when you call `gnls`, it takes the last argument`gnlsControl(nlsTol=0.01, nlsMaxIter=20)` as `params` (see `?gnls`) instead of `control` which is what you want. So try naming it, ie adding `control=` in front of the last argument.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. By adding in the `control=`, the `out-of-bounds` error disappears. However, I am now left with the error `step halving factor reduced below minimum in NLS step`, which I have come across before. Increasing the `nlsTol` in order of magnitude increments to 1000 still produces the same problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't really know about that. Maybe you could try playing around with your initial values a bit and see if that solves it. Otherwise, I suggest you edit the question with the new problem and someone else may be able to help

Comment: I got it to work by adjusting the initial values. Thanks!